# WPF binding background

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm using a style in App.xaml and I want to change background color.

App.xaml background code:

```
<Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding anamenuhover}"></Setter>
```

And my background function:

```
public SolidColorBrush anamenuhover()
    {
            SolidColorBrush anamenuhoverbg = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 7, 12, 72));
            return anamenuhoverbg;  
    }
```

Why did that not work?

Comment: that my complete code app.xaml   https://ibb.co/nqJpXm

Answer (score 0):

Binding needs a property not a function/method

You should have a code similar to this:

```
private SolidColorBrush _anamenuhover = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 7, 12, 72));

public SolidColorBrush Anamenuhover {
    get { return _anamenuhover;}
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: that didnt work :( Can you control my app.xaml code https://ibb.co/nqJpXm

Comment: What's your data context? you put the code in your data context?

Comment: And don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.